# C/C++ - Understanding Audio interpolation code

Tags: c, audio, interpolation, packets

The code below is intended to implement two strategies to interpolate across missing packets - the two strategies are 1) fill the gap with silence, or 2) repeat the previous packet and if longer than one packet fill the rest with silence.  The code has broad comments but I can't seem to get my head around what the different variables are supposed to mean.  Would someone mind giving me a helping hand understanding this code?  Appreciate any guidance!

```
#include "interpolate.h"
#include "assert.h"

/* write a packet's worth of silence */
void write_silence(FILE *ofile, int num_samples) {
  short missing_pkt[num_samples];
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < num_samples; i++) {
    missing_pkt[i]=0;
  }
  fwrite(missing_pkt, 1, num_samples*2, ofile);
}

/* simulate the reception of a packet, and apply a loss repair strategy */
void recv_packet(int seqno, int len, char *data, FILE *ofile, int strategy) {
  static int prev_seqno = -1;
  static short* prev_samples = 0;

  /* interpret the data as signed 16 bit integers */
  short *samples = (short*)data; 
  int num_samples = len/2;

  printf("recv_packet: seqno=%d\n", seqno);

  if (prev_seqno != -1 && (prev_seqno+1 != seqno)) {
    int i, missing_seqno;
    /* there was missing data */

    printf("s=%d\n", strategy);
    switch(strategy) {
    case SILENCE: 
      {
    /* create a packet containing silence */
    missing_seqno = prev_seqno + 1;
    while (missing_seqno < seqno) {
      write_silence(ofile, num_samples);
      missing_seqno++;
    }
    break;
      }
    case REPEAT_PREV: 
      {
    /* repeat the previous packet */
    fwrite(prev_samples, 2, num_samples, ofile);
    missing_seqno = prev_seqno + 2;
    while (missing_seqno < seqno) {
      /* repeating the same packet more than once sounds bad */
      write_silence(ofile, num_samples);
      missing_seqno++;
    }
    break;
      }

    default:
      abort();
    }
  }

  fwrite(samples, 1, num_samples*2, ofile);

  /* hold onto the last received packet - we may need it */
  if (prev_samples != 0)
    free(prev_samples);
  prev_samples = samples;
  prev_seqno = seqno;
};
```

Comment: Once you've figured it out, make sure you add some kind of fade between the good packet and the interpolated one; otherwise, the discontinuity will cause a horrific click.

Comment: take some time to understand C syntax and basic functions you will need. Seems you are not familiar yet. (ps not C++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables convention :

- `seqno` : sequence number
- `samples` : audio data as samples
- `prev_` : previous
- `ofile` : output file

How do you know what the code is supposed to do without understanding it?
The idea is that packets have incremental sequence numbers, from 0 to infinity. -1 is the initial state, when no packets have even been received.
When you receive a packet and

```
  if (prev_seqno != -1 //it is not the first packet 
      && 
     (prev_seqno+1 != seqno) //the packet is not the one we expected  
      ){ 
   //there are (seqno - prev_seqno - 1) packet missing.
   //do something about it.
```

when you enter this condition then you have a gap. Depending on the strategy you fill the output file `ofile` with silence or copy of the last samples received. In audio `silence = 0`.

For example, if the last packet was 0 and you received packet 4, it means packet 1, 2 and 3 are missing. In this case depending on the strategy you will consider 1, 2, 3 as silence packets or as 0 being repeated.

Comment: Thanks for the help UmNyobe (like the name!) This is part of an exercise for exam prep - the exercise involves implementing some more strategies, but before I can do that I need to understand the code.  The question says what those strategies are supposed to do.

Can I ask, why do the sequence numbers start from -1?  Also, I can't seem to grasp why the condition:

prev_seqno != -1 && (prev_seqno+1 != seqno)

constitutes a gap.  Would you mind elaborating?  Thanks

Comment: -1 was just a choice, it could have been anything. let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I understand the second clause now, but isn't this saying that a gap can only exist if the previous sequence number wasn't the first packet?  Surely this is incorrect because you could receive the first packet, miss the second and receive the third i.e. get -1, 1 as sequence numbers?

Comment: i wrote something confusing. -1 means "no packets have ever been received". 0 is the seq number of the first packet.

Comment: The REPEAT_PREV strategy repeats the previous packet, and for any remaining packets in the gap fills them will silence.  To do this it has a fwrite function which the API says takes an array containing the information to write.  In this case we only want to repeat the one previous sample - how is it choosing that one sample?  How would you write the previous TWO samples say?  prev_samples seems to be declared but doesn't seem to be updated at any other point either...

Comment: prev_sample is updated at the end of the function you provided. Anyway this is another question and I think it is better if you think about your strategies yourself.